# Multiple timers in Python (Pygame)

Tags: python, time, pygame

I'm an amateur programmer. I am trying to write a simple program that will measure the reaction time for a series of visual stimuli (flashes of squares) that will be used for a biology experiment. Here's my code (beware, first time coding a graphical interface):

```
stimulus = pygame.Rect(100,250,100,100)

#draw on surface object
time.sleep(2) #wait for 2 seconds before it appears
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,stimulus)
pygame.display.update(stimulus)

#record time stimulus appeared
t0 = time.clock()

#clear screen ("flash" illusion)
time.sleep(0.5) #***PROBLEM***
screen.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.update(stimulus) 


while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            t1 = time.clock()
            print t1-t0
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

The program was working fine before I included the block with the line marked "problem". The reaction time printed seemed reasonable. However, I want the square to disappear after a while, as though it just "flashed". After including the time.sleep(0.5), the time printed is no longer correct. It is always 0.5xxxx or greater, no matter how fast I press. Is there any workaround?

P.S. I need it to disappear because I want to present a sequence of flashes with predetermined (not constant) pauses in between.

Thanks.

**Edit**

I need to achieve two things: 
1. The shape must flash on the screen for 0.5 sec. 2. The program must create a timestamp (e.g. write to a list) every time the spacebar is pressed (even if it is pressed randomly twice between two flashes).

Comment: There is no way to have perfect timing accuracy. When you call `time.sleep` the OS puts the process in a suspended state, then when *at least* `0.5` seconds are passed an interrupt will wake the OS which will put your program in running state. If you want almost perfect timings you should use special real-time OSes.

Comment: Can you post code that is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). It would make it easier for people to help you. the names screen, BLACK, WHITE, KEYDOWN have not been imported or defined, so I am unable to run your code.

Comment: @Bakuriu Any suggestions for a "real-time OS" that runs Python? Thanks.

Comment: There isn't any real-time OS in which Python runs. Usually this kind of OS is used in micro-controllers, airplane chips etc. where they have to do "simple" tasks but the timings are crucial, and even on these systems the timings of events cannot be perfect, they have a certain time-period in which it is guaranteed that they happen. What I wanted to say is that if you do `sleep(0.5)` you can only know that the timings differ for at least `0.5` seconds, but no other guaranteed is provided. Usually the OS takes some extra millisecond, but it depends on processes running.

Comment: Oh, I understand now. That's alright for my purposes. It's just a project for school so it doesn't need to be extremely accurate. I just want to get it as precise as I can with the basic equipment I have. Thanks.

Comment: @MarwanAlsabbagh Thanks for the link. I will keep that in mind for my future posts.

Comment: @Jey No worries, I've recently discovered it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the computer will be doing nothing for 0.5 seconds due to the line you marked as a problem.  What you need to do is make it so it is possible for the reaction to be registered while the square is still being shown.  Instead of having `time.sleep(0.5)`, put this:

```
while time.clock()-t0<0.5:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            t1 = time.clock()
            print t1-t0
```

This should fix your code.

Comment: I don't think this will work for my needs. I need to achieve two things: 1. The shape must flash on the screen for 0.5 sec. 2. The program must create a timestamp (e.g. write to a list) every time the spacebar is pressed (even if it is pressed randomly twice between two flashes).

Comment: @Jey This will achieve both things.  Because of the while loop on the first line, it will only go through the checking for if the key is pressed for 0.5 seconds, then clear the screen.  The code you already have will take care of the second item.  Just try it and you will see.

Comment: Use this answer, except what is time.clock()? Make sure it returns milliseconds since init , like `get_ticks` not since last call, like `Clock.tick`

Comment: Wow, you're right, it works! I didn't really understand what the while loop was doing. I think I get it now: It "pauses" the program for 0.5 sec & it allows you to register keypresses unlike time.sleep. Thanks.  

@monkey This is what I found about [time.clock](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/time_clock.htm)
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` which gives you milliseconds elapsed since `pygame.init`

edit:

If you save the `get_ticks` value when the shape is first shown, then every keydown, append to your list the current `get_ticks`.

```
for press in press_times:
    print "milliseconds: {}".format(press - time_start)
```

Milliseconds meaning 500 is equivalent to 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Is this more precise than time.clock or time.time?

Comment: @Jey it is actually less precise.  Don't use it.